# Finding(drawing) interior, boundary and closure of a given 2D visual representation of a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I'm currently studying for my exam in Geospatial Databases and I've come across a question which I'm not quite sure how to solve.

We're given a visual topological space (picture below) and we need to draw the interior, boundary and closure of this space.

I understand what these terms represent but I'm not quite sure how to transfer them to a visual domain.

This is the given space:

[image: This is the given space:]

This is my "solution":

[image]

I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this type of question.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what the conventions are for these diagrams, and given the questions asked, I'd say calling it a "space" is incorrect, since it obviously is to be considered as a subset of a larger space (the plane). But presuming the original diagram indicates the area between the two dashed rectangles (without border) and the square area (with border), then your answers are correct.

Comment: In any topological space $X$, if $A\subseteq X$ then the sets $int(X),int(X\setminus A),\partial (X)$ are pairwise-disjoint and their union is $X$. Now $int(X\setminus A)$ is the union of all open subsets that are disjoint from $A$ so its complement $int(X)\cup \partial (X)=X\setminus(int(A\setminus X))$ is the intersection of all closed sets that have $A$ as a subset, which is (by definition) $\overline A$. So $\overline A=int(A)\cup \partial (A).$... (continued)...

Comment: ...(continued)... I often visualize $int(A)$ as $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: x^2+y^2<1\}$ and $\partial(A)$ as $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=1\}.$ But this can be mis-leading. It seems to suggest that $\partial(A)$ is "small" and seems to  suggest that $int(A)$ is  a regular-open set. (An open set $U$ is regular-open iff $U=int(\overline U).$ Similarly a closed set $V$ is regular-closed iff $V=\overline {int(V)}$...)

Comment: Yes, I've probably used wrong terminology and calling it a subset is more accurate. Thanks for the insight. @PaulSinclair